# Disable toggle inheritance from parent tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, inheritance

Hi i was wondering if it is possible to override or disable inheritance from a parent tag.

what i want to do is to be able to make use if the "input-group" class but having a particular tag not inheriting the toggle function from the parent a-tag.

the reason i'm doing this is because i'm using a plugin and i want to add a button looking consistent with the overall theme.

Here is some code:

```html
<div class="col-lg-12 col-md-6">
  <lable class="lfInputLable">From date</lable>
  <div class="dropdown">
    <a class="dropdown-toggle" id="dropdown1" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#">
      <div class="input-group">
        
        <!-- COMMENT: i want the span tag shown under this comment NOT to inherit the a-tag's toggle function, it being inside it and all -->
        
        <span type="button" id="dateRemove" class="input-group-addon" ng-click="clearToDate()"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></i></span>
        
        
        
        <input type="text" class="form-control" data-ng-model="data1.dateDropDownInput1" data-date-time-input="YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm" disabled="disabled"><span class="input-group-addon"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></span>
      </div>
    </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dLabel">
      <datetimepicker data-ng-model="data1.dateDropDownInput1" data-datetimepicker-config="{ dropdownSelector: '#dropdown1' }" />
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

So is this at all possible?

Comment: The given HTML is invalid, [`<a>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) can't contain interactive elements. Also, probably you need `<label>`, not `<lable>`?

Comment: Hahaha sorry, your right about the <label> tag, free-wrote half of it :P
Well the whole snippet except the span with the remove glyph-icon and the comment is from a date picker plugin. and editing or changing it renders it nonfunctional.